# How can I devise an experiment that compares the performance of the del operator on lists and dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm want to solve programming exercise no.3 in [problem solving with algorithms and data structures using python ch.2](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/AlgorithmAnalysis/ProgrammingExercises.html). The exercise wants me to devise an experiment that compares the performance of the del operator on lists and dictionaries.

My code is

```
import timeit
import random

for i in range(10000,1000001,20000):
    t = timeit.Timer("del x[random.randrange(%d)]" % i, "from __main__ import random, x")
    x = list(range(i))
    lst_time = t.timeit(number=1000)
    x = {j:None for j in range(i)}
    d_time = t.timeit(number=1000)
    print("%d,%10.3f,%10.3f" % (i, lst_time, d_time))
```

But it fails with an error message IndexError:

> list assignment index out of range.

How can i fix the code to solve exercise no. 3?

Comment: In addition to the problem you are having: Your `del x[random.randrange(%d)]" % i` times both `randrange` and `del`. That is a bad timing. Try timing only `del` without other calls.

Comment: The problem itself is that as you call `del` many times (`timeit` does it), the list becomes smaller so you at some time try deleting items which are mo longer there. Try making a new list each time (but don't time the creation of the list)

Comment: @zvone Thanks for your clever comments. I realized what my problem is. Also I should admit I was timing both 'randrange' and 'del' truly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`del` mutates the list in place so you're reducing its size, but you're never adjusting the `randrange` per timeit loop to compensate - eg - the `randrange` picked will always be the original size of the list, hence it's possible to pick a value larger than the list is currently and attempting to `del` it will give you the `IndexError`. You can adjust your timeit to use the randrange with the length of the list at the time instead of a hardcoded starting point, eg:

```
t = timeit.Timer("del x[random.randrange(len(x))]", "from __main__ import random, x")
```

Side note: `x = {j:None for j in range(i)}` can be written as `x = dict.fromkeys(range(i))`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I found bugs in my code. And now I can solve my problem using the code you loaded.